# Список аудио файлов android устройства

Tags: java, android, аудио, android-dialog

Возник вопрос - как получить список аудио файлов с устройства и вывести на экран в диалоговом окне. Поиск в интернете не дал информации на русском языке,а в английском я профан:)
Кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой?

Comment: Это нужно для выбора какого-то звука, например, установки музыки для напоминания?

Comment: Угадали,я пишу будильник,и мне нужно выбирать музыку,которая будет проигрываться при срабатывании.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В обработке нажатия на кнопку выбора аудио вставьте следующий код:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER)
    .putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
    .putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Choose audio")
    .putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_SILENT, true)
    .putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
```

Это позволит пользователю выбрать музыку. На некоторых устройствах сначала будет предложено выбрать приложение, через которое будет происходить выбор. Вы можете задать заголовок для окна с выбором, будет ли предложено выбрать Без звука и т.д. Подробности [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html).

Дальше нужно обработать выбор пользователя этим кодом:

```
@Override
 protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent intent)
 {
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 3)
     {
          Uri toneUri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);

          if (toneUri != null)
          {
              this.chosenRingtone = toneUri.toString();
          }
          else
          {
              this.chosenRingtone = null;
          }
      }            
  }
```

Comment: Большое спасибо)